# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError while reading all files and nested files from a Directory

Tags: java, stack-overflow, java-io

### With this program I'm trying to read all files in a given folder location, also if there is further a directory or sub-folder, then the program should be able to read the files in the sub-folder as well.

This condition reads all the files:- `if(listOfFiles[i].isFile())` 
and this `else if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())` condition tells whether there is any sub folder.
If there is a subfolder, then I again called the same method. i.e: `ft.fileChecker(s2);`

But at this step it throws a run-time error.

```
//Main class
  public class FileCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "C:\\Users\\Nitk\\Desktop\\Project";    
    FileTester ftMain = new FileTester();
    ftMain.fileChecker(s);
}}

//----------
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 public class FileTester {
    FileTester ft = new FileTester();
    public void fileChecker(String folderPath) {
        File f = new File(folderPath);
        File[] listOfFiles = f.listFiles(); 
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        FileLineCounter flc = new FileLineCounter();
        int count = 0;
        boolean isFound; boolean isFoundTxt;
        String s = null;                         
              for(int i =0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
                    if(listOfFiles[i].isFile()){
                        System.out.println(i +". File:" + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                        s = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                        list.add(s);
                       }else if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                      System.out.println(i +". Directory: " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                      String s2 = folderPath+"\\"+listOfFiles[i];
                      ft.fileChecker(s2);
                   } 
            }              
       }     
  } 

Output:
--------
 Run-time error: 
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at FileTester.<init>(FileTester.java:3)
    at FileTester.<init>(FileTester.java:4)
 ...
    at FileTester.<init>(FileTester.java:4)
    at FileTester.<init>(FileTester.java:4)
  C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke the constructor of class `FileTester`, the field `ft` is initialized. Since `ft` is of type `FileTester`, initializing said field means invoking the constructor of class `FileTester` again which initializes the `ft` field which invokes the constructor which initializes the `ft` field which invokes the constructor ...

In short, removed the line `FileTester ft = new FileTester();` from class `FileTester`.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code has 2 flaws.**

1. You are creating Objects of the same class inside that object, when you can just use the method of that class, Dont `FileTester ft = new FileTester();` inside FileTester Class,
   instead just use `fileChecker()`.
2. When you encounter a directory and invoke fileChecker(), you are passing wrong directory to it , you should pass `String s2 = folderPath+"\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName(); fileChecker(s2);`

Comment: Glad it helped! also please select the answer as accepted! :)